# Journey working in Test, but Live doesn't appear to be working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Have a simple email Journey I am working on with this criteria:

Who: AccountID (PersonAccount)
Object: Opportunity
Action: Created
Criteria: Product_Start__c WASSET

I am able to start the Journey by creating an Opportunity and having including a date on the Product_Start__c just fine. My only issue was as a company we sync opportunities at night from another platform. The API creates the opportunity and meets the criteria but the journey doesn't start. It didn't even evaluate them as being potential entry's. I am not sure what I am missing here, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could the API create the opportunity before setting the Product_Start__c date? Try setting it to Created/Changed to see if it has any effect.

Comment: That is an excellent point Lukas. I will do some testing on this to see! I would think it maps all together, but since that Product_Start__c is functioning off of a roll up then it technically would have a window after the opportunity was created in which it is evaluating to determine if it is correct. Ill connect back and let you know.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Did you manage to identify the root cause here?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Your solution was the answer, the workflow wasn't firing just fast enough to be recognized with the entry. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries- I added my comment as an actual answer with some more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the API create the opportunity before setting the Product_Start__c date? Try setting it to Created/Changed to see if it has any effect. In some cases the changes occur after the process Builder triggers the entry event (in step 13 of below order of execution):

1. Original record is loaded or new record is initialized
2. Fields values are loaded into sObjects
3. System validations rules are executed
4. Before triggers are executed
5. System validations rules are run again and custom validation rules are checked.
6. Duplicate rules are executed
7. Record is saved but not committed
8. After triggers are executed
9. Assignment rules are executed
10. Auto-response rules are executed
11. Workflow rules are executed
12. Before triggers,system validation rules and after triggers are executed due to workflow field updates
13. Processes are executed
14. Escalation rules are executed
15. Entitlement rules are executed
16. Rull-up summary fields and cross-object formula fields are updated
17. Updated parent and grand parent records are saved
18. Criteria based sharing rules are evaluated
19. DML operations are committed to the database
20. Post-commit logic is executed

And as you write in one of your comments: *"...Product_Start__c is functioning off of a roll up..."* (step 16) this will be too late to be evaluated in the journey trigger (step 13).